# Spark unpersisting dataframe after it has been persisted agai due to shuffle

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say we have the following scenario:

```
val df: DataFrame = dataframe
val df2 = df.partition(col("id").cache
...
some transformations/joins by "id" resulting `val dfTransformed`
...
val df3 = dfTransformed.groupBy("name").agg(<someaggregations>)
val df4 = df3.partition(col("id").cache
...
some transformations/joins by "id"...
...
```

My question is do I need at some time to unpersist df2? Or when I persist df4 then it automatically overwrites df2?

If I need to unpersist df2 then when to unpersist it?

If I do:

```
val df3 = df2.groupBy("name").agg(<someaggregations>)
df2.unpersist
val df4 = df3.partition(col("id").cache
```

Won't I losse some performance due to removing data from memory?

If I do:

```
val df3 = df2.groupBy("name").agg(<someaggregations>)
val df4 = df3.partition(col("id").cache
df2.unpersist
```

Won't I unpersist df4 actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or when I persist df4 then it automatically overwrites df2?

Spark doesnt overwrite df2, because you may have a different branch of computation DAG started from df2, something like

```
val df4 = df3.partition(col("id").cache
val df2_1 = df2.groupBy("another_name")
```

> Won't I losse some performance due to removing data from memory?

In general yes. The main thing you need to know is that Spark does lazy executions. So on the stage

```
val df3 = f2.groupBy("name").agg(<someaggregations>)
```

nothing actually happens. Look at official Spark guide of transformations and actions.

> Won't I unpersist df4 actually?

No.